# WPF Automation of UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on implementing a joystick into my WPF app.  I would like to simulate clicking on buttons.  I can run the events with the code below, but I want to also show the button being clicked in the UI.  Is this possible for button and other UI items?

```
 var invokeProv = (IInvokeProvider) (new ButtonAutomationPeer(ButtonHome).GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke));
            invokeProv?.Invoke();

 ButtonHome.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

I ended up with this as a possible solution. In the mainwindow class I put...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonPressedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonPressed", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

added a property...

```
       private bool ButtonPressed
    {
        get => (bool) GetValue(ButtonPressedProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonPressedProperty, value);

    }
```

In the mainwindow xaml under the button I put ...

```
<Button.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=(windows:MainWindow.ButtonPressed)}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedButtonBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForeground}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=(windows:MainWindow.ButtonPressed)}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForeground}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Evaluating my joystick buttons i just used ButtonPressed = gamepadButtons[3];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that comes to my mind is if I was on your place I'd simply create data trigger on the xaml side as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Height="30" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="bd"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ButtonPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

then I'd create a property:

```
    private bool _buttonPressed;
    public bool ButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonPressed;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_buttonPressed != value)
            {
                _buttonPressed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonPressed));
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the place that you're about to raise that event I'd simply change our boolean value state

```
        var invokeProv = (IInvokeProvider)(new ButtonAutomationPeer(ButtonHome).GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke));
        invokeProv?.Invoke();

        ButtonHome.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
        ButtonPressed = true;
```

The things that you have to remember about within this solution:

- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
- Make sure that your button template can reach the datacontext, where our property is created, for example I've setup RelativeSource to the Window ancestor type which isn't really nessecary i think. You might do it better and faster.

If there's a better solution for raising visual state of UI elements I'd like to know about it! Kind Regards.

Comment: Your ideas led me to the solution I put in my original post.  --Thanks